# how can I resolve an unconfirmed deposit to my blockchain.info wallet?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, wallet, mining-pools, security

After 35 hours and still Unconfirmed bitcoin deposit to my blockchain.info wallet after I sweeped the bitcoins I have in my paperwallet which I created on bitaddress.org.

Hello everyone, this is my first time having a problem with unconfirmed bitcoin transactions!  I hope somebody can help me resolve this issue by sharing their 
knowledge and experience and point me in the right direction, thank you so much in advance!

About 35 hours ago, I used the blockchain.info wallet to sweep a bitcoin paper wallet private address where some of my bitcoins were stored!
(I created the paper wallet address on bitaddress.org., and I have been storing bitcoins like this and sweeping it with blockchain.info wallet for the
past year and a half without ever any problems regarding delayed transactions.)

Anyway, this time after the wallet was successfully sweeped, and the bitcoins were transferred from my paper wallet to my blockchain.info wallet, 
it sits indicating as a pending transaction awaiting confirmation.

If I send some of that funds out by setting a higher priority transaction fee, would that help confirm both transactions?

My paper wallet public key which I sweeped the funds from is:  1EwT9GvF5vvRq4wW1YS1h4cLgJqdEiF4Mg

Please help me check the status, and let me know how I may resolve this unconfirmed transaction asap, thank you so much for your kind assistance! 
Dave

Comment: accelerated.....

Comment: Probably your fee was too low. If you increase the fee, the transaction will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Every transaction has everything it needs to process, so you cannot really boost the priority of the transaction already on the network. If your transaction is not confirmed , i am assuming you have set low fees or there is unusual load on network, at current time of writing it does not look too bad.

If you send another transaction with higher fees , it will get confirmed quicker and the earlier one will be removed from the pool at some point (or will get rejected as you will have already spent your inputs).*

*Assuming here you are trying to spend everything in the address.